# Ruby raise method and implicit coercion

Tags: ruby

Consider the two following ways to raise an exception -

```
class ExampleError < StandardError; end

raise ExampleError.new

raise ExampleError
```

In the first way, an instance of `ExampleError` is given to the method `raise`.  The `raise` method can accept an `Exception` parameter and everything is clear.

In the second way a `Class` instance is given to the method, yet this still works.

Due to the fact that `raise` can accept `String`, was there implicit conversion of the parameter from `Class` to `String`?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not get converted to `String`. In fact, your assumption was wrong. `raise` doesn't want an instance of some exception class. It would rather have the exception class itself. See documentation for [Kernel#raise](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-raise):

> ... With a single String argument, raises a RuntimeError with the string as a message. Otherwise, the first parameter should be the name of an Exception class (or an object that returns an Exception object when sent an exception message). ...

So, you can pass anything to `raise`, as long as it's a string or has `exception` method. Both your variants pass here:

```
class ExampleError < StandardError; end

ExampleError.exception # => #<ExampleError: ExampleError>
ExampleError.new.exception # => #<ExampleError: ExampleError>
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the help and the quick reply but this does not answer my question.  Sure ex.class is ExampleError but that's after you rescue it.  The original value you gave was an instance of Class

Comment: It is worth noting that the Exception class has two methods named exception - one is a class method and one is an instance method and this is what allows for this behavior.